# how to update a mongodb document from node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update an array in a mongoDB from a node.js program.  I am able to modify the array from within node.js, but I can not get the changes to save.

http://pastebin.com/j0Mnf7jP

I think I am doing something very wrong.
assistance would be appreciated...

Comment: You can do this from mongo shell alone.

Answer (score 11):

Change this line:

```
({_id:doc._id},$set:{scores:zz});
```

To:

```
({_id:doc._id}, { $set:{scores:zz}} );
```

This should also probably be wrapped with a callback, to catch errors:

```
db.schools.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{scores:zz}}, function(err, result) {
    if (err)
        //do something.
});
```

Comment: I did this...  But I am getting this error...   TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of undefined

Comment: @IrishGringo -- sounds like your `db` or `schools` is undefined.

Comment: use db.collection( 'students' ) instead of db.schools

Comment: The callback is essential!

Had other api routes in my app(write/reads), and copied the format of one, before trying to perform an update action. I took out the callback to maintain function simplicity. Have spent the past hour trying to get an update to occur, when all worked fine within the shell.

Comment: what is result in this case?

Answer (score 8):

I know it's a bit late to help you now, but maybe others can benefit as new cohorts pass through MongoDB University!

`db.schools.update` should read `db.students.update`.

@tymeJV's answer gives the rest:

- Wrap the `$set` inside braces: `{$set:{scores:zz}}`
- Add a callback function to catch errors:

  ```
  db.collection( 'students' ).update (
      { _id : doc._id },
      { $set : { scores:zz } },
      function( err, result ) {
          if ( err ) throw err;
      }
  );
  ```

Funnily enough, I'm actually doing exactly the same assignment right now! I had a different issue that was answered by reading the docs, but I saw this question while googling for it. Hope I helped someone!

Answer (score 1):

```
var dbName = 'school'
var tableName = 'classA'
MongoClient.connect(dbName, function(err, db) {
  if (err)
  {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {

    var collection = db.collection(tableName)
    collection.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{scores:zz}}, function(err, result) {
      if (err)
      {
        console.log(err);

      }
      else{
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do following code for solving issues

```
    var lowScore = 9999.9;
        for ( var i=0; i<doc.scores.length; i++ ) {
            if ( doc.scores[i].type == "homework"
               && doc.scores[i].score < lowScore ) {
                    lowScore = doc.scores[i].score;
            }
        }
```

and then update your collection using following query

```
collection.update({ "_id":doc._id }, 
{ $pull : { "scores" : {
$and: [ {"type":"homework"}, { "score":lowScore} ]
} } },
{ "safe":true },
function( err, result ) {
if (err) {
 console.log(err);
  }
} // update callback
);
```

for more info you can refer  [here](https://gist.github.com/ronasta/4080463)